# Javascript/Canvas Jquery Guessing game time loop

Tags: javascript, timer

Please help I'm so stuck. I've been coding this for almost 1 month now and I'm more confused now than when I started. Here's a snippet :

```
    const $inputs = $("#number input")
    const $form = $("#number");
    $inputs.on("input", function() {
      if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
        const $next = $(this).next('#number input');
        if ($next.length) $next.focus();
        if ($inputs.filter(function() {
            return this.value !== ""
          }).length === $inputs.length) {
          $form.submit();
          checkInput();
        }
      }
    });
```

Here's the JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/viwe/18yhtuo6/2/
Desired behaviour : user must enter the time, code must check the user's answer and keep a score of correct and incorrect answers. This must all happen within a given game time. (ideally I would love to have a drop-down menu and select the game time from there (extra) but for now a just need the code to work.
Stuck point : Page reloads every time user submits an answer (Thereby restarting the scores  and time left)

Comment: As I said already: Remove `$form.submit();` and instead call an Ajax function when you need to. Alternatively save the time/score in localStorage

Comment: can you ensure that your code is running in your fiddle? Currently it's bugging and not doing anything

Comment: also, please clarify what it means to submit the answer. There is no button to click to submit, so what is submitting answer?

Comment: I don't know why the inputs are not showing up in JS fiddle. The markup is there and I did the queryselectors in the JS. The CSS is there. So I'm stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things

1. I created some global vars to hold the time
2. I moved the createTime code into its own function to be reused
3. cleaned up some code

The script does not time out  - that will be next question for you

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3mbqw80h/

```js
function createTime() {
  // create new date object and randomize the time, storing hr,min and sec in own variables
  const now = new Date();
  let hours = now.getUTCHours() * Math.random();
  let minutes = now.getUTCMinutes() * Math.random();
  let seconds = now.getUTCSeconds() * Math.random();

  // Format the time variables
  hours = Math.round(hours.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    hour: 'numeric', // numeric, 2-digit
  }));
  minutes = Math.round(minutes.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minute: 'numeric', // numeric, 2-digit
  }));
  seconds = Math.round(seconds.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    second: 'numeric', // numeric, 2-digit
  }));

  return {
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  }
}
let time = createTime();
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
let correctAnswers = [];
let incorrectAnswers = [];
drawClock();

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbersSecs(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius) {
  let {
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  } = time;

  // console.log(hour)
  //hour
  // Calculate the angle of the hour hand, and draw it a length 
  // (50% of radius), and a width (7% of radius):
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = (hours * Math.PI / 6) + (minutes * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) + (seconds * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
  drawHand(ctx, hours, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.04);
  //minute
  minutes = (minutes * Math.PI / 30) + (seconds * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
  drawHand(ctx, minutes, radius * 0.7, radius * 0.03);
  // second
  seconds = (seconds * Math.PI / 30);
  drawHand(ctx, seconds, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;

  // face
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();

  // outer ring
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.02);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  // grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#fff');
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.02;
  ctx.stroke();

  // inner circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.04, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  // Set the font size (of the drawing object) to 15% of the 
  // radius:
  ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  // Set the text alignment to the middle and the center of the
  // print position:
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  // Calculate the print position (for 12 numbers) to 85% of the 
  // radius, rotated (PI/6) for each number:
  for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

// Draw the  minute / second numbers
function drawNumbersSecs(ctx, radius) {
  let ang;
  let num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.06 + "px helvetica";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (num = 1; num < 61; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / 30;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 1.06);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 1.06);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}
// Evaluate the user's input
function checkInput() {
  let {
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  } = time;
  let uHr = uHrs.value;
  let uMin = uMins.value;
  let uSec = uSecs.value;
  const m = document.querySelector("h2");

  if (uHr == hours && uMin == minutes && uSec == seconds) {
    correctAnswers.push({
      "time": time,
      "answer": {
        uHr,
        uMin,
        uSec
      }
    })
    console.log(correctAnswers);
    m.style.background = "green";
    m.innerHTML = "correct";

  } else {
    incorrectAnswers.push({
      "time": time,
      "answer": {
        uHr,
        uMin,
        uSec
      }
    })
    console.log(incorrectAnswers);
    m.style.background = "red";
    m.innerHTML = "incorrect"

  }
  $("#right").html("Correct: " + correctAnswers.length);
  $("#wrong").html("Incorrect: " + incorrectAnswers.length);
  console.log(correctAnswers.length)
  document.getElementById("number").reset();
  time = createTime();
  setTimeout(drawClock, 1000);
}


// Jump to next input box and run checkInput
$(function() {

  const $inputs = $("#number input"),
    $form = $("#number");
  $inputs.on("input", function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      const $next = $(this).next('#number input');
      if ($next.length) $next.select().focus();
      if ($inputs.filter(function() {
          return this.value.trim() !== ""
        }).length === $inputs.length) {
        checkInput();
      }
    }
  });

})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.hide {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  left: 30%;
  overflow: none;
}

canvas {
  margin: 1em;
}

form input {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 12.5%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}


@keyframes hello {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 460px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  animation-name: hello;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

#score {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 6.75em;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

form button {
  margin: 0 2em;
  padding: 0 0.6em;
}

#right {
  color: green;
}

#wrong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="520" height="520"></canvas>

  <div>

    <form id="number">
      <input placeholder="hr" type="number" maxlength="2" value="" id="uHrs" pattern="[1-12]" autofocus />
      <input placeholder="min" type="number" maxlength="2" value="" id="uMins" pattern="[0-59]" />
      <input placeholder="sec" type="number" maxlength="2" value="" id="uSecs" pattern="[0-59]" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="score">
    <h6 id="game_time">Minutes left: </h6>
    <h4 id="right">Correct : </h4>
    <h4 id="wrong">Incorrect : </h4>
  </div>
  <h2 id="mark"></h2>


</div>
>
```

Comment: Aha yes I see but I will have to practise some more so I fully understand. Lots of great keywords/clues in comments too. Thank you so much so taking the time and for being so patient with me. I truly grateful

Comment: Aha yes I see but I will have to practise some more so I fully understand. Lots of great keywords/clues in comments too. Thank you so much so taking the time and for being so patient with me. I truly grateful